# Calling class defined in project from cassandra udf

Tags: java, cassandra

When defining a UDF (User Defined Function) in cassandra you have to write the actual code. When I write a UDF is it possible to access a class defined in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. UDFs are loaded with a specific security manager and a specific class loader that forbid many things, including access to Cassandra internals, access to external libraries, I/O operations, etc. Basically, your UDFs should be "pure", i.e., have no side effects and operate only on their input parameters.